# Where can I download ArcGIS Service Pack 2?

Tags: arcgis-10.0

I understand SP2 is available for download. http://blogs.esri.com/support/blogs/supportcenter/archive/2011/04/20/arcpad-10-0-service-pack-2-released.aspx

> We are pleased to announce that
>   Service Pack 2 for ArcPad 10.0 is now
>   available to download at the Esri
>   Customer Care website.

Maybe I am missing something but when I log into the ESRI customer care website the Service Pack is not listed.

Anyone?

Comment: http://resources.arcgis.com/content/patches-and-service-packs?fa=listPatches&PID=26 but not listed be ESRI (someone forgot to add the link)

Comment: Service Pack 2: http://resources.arcgis.com/content/patches-and-service-packs?fa=viewPatch&PID=17&MetaID=1752

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the Support site http://support.esri.com then click the Patches and Service Packs link.

[SP2](http://resources.arcgis.com/content/patches-and-service-packs?fa=viewPatch&PID=17&MetaID=1752)

Comment: @Brad Nesom, the link you provided, I do not see ArcPad listed, however I'm unsure if @Jakub is wanting ArcGIS 10 sp2 or ArcPad 10 sp2?

Comment: Yes my apologies. I was looking for the ArcGIS not ArcPad. Thanks Brad.

Comment: @jakub was just confusing that your links relate to ARCPAD announcements in your question.

Answer (score 2):

It is available for download here:
http://resources.arcgis.com/content/patches-and-service-packs?fa=viewPatch&PID=17&MetaID=1746

But I recommend you read this first:
http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/29494-Service-Pack-2-Reference-Scale-Issue

We have delayed our install due to the impact this would have on our workflow.